# SQL 2 where clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, razor-3

I have a fairly simple query which I am trying to execute on my website, all though, it just won't work. I'm using 2 where clauses, and yes, I have seen many of the other questions about multiple where clauses, my query is just very different from theirs as their queries are much more complicated and advanced, and so I can't really get the solutions to work for me.

Here's my query;

```
SELECT * FROM ImpoundReports WHERE (UserId = @0 AND Released = 0)
```

The query "works", as in it doesn't give me any error, it just doesn't pull out the report as it's supposed to.

UserId is an int.
Released is a bit.

UserId = @0 is a scalar variable used in my Razor code.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Run two queries where each of them has a part of your where clause. Do they both give the required result?

Comment: "UserId = @0", is this correct?

Comment: this question is not clear, please clarify the data types of UserId and Released, Plus why are u using **@0** ? is this is a string ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick replies, it turns out changing Released to say "Released is null" works.

I've edited my question to have the datatypes, and the @0 is a scalar variable which I use in my C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the question if **Released** is bit, then its possible values are **true**, **false** and **null** (if null is acceptable)

so the possible result queries are..

```
    SELECT * FROM ImpoundReports WHERE (UserId = @0 AND Released is null)
    SELECT * FROM ImpoundReports WHERE (UserId = @0 AND Released is true)
    SELECT * FROM ImpoundReports WHERE (UserId = @0 AND Released is false)
```

Comment: Thank you!! Nulls are allowed, so using Released is null fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ImpoundReports WHERE (UserId = @0 AND Released is null)
```

This fixed it. "Released is null" instead of "Released = 0".